# Adding audio to video with ffmpeg not working

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg

I try to add audio to a video with ffmpeg.

**Here´s my code:**

`ffmpeg -i $videoPath -i ${finalSong.path} -codec copy -shortest $tempPath/$newVideoFileName.mp4")`

Without the `-shortest` the video duration is the long duration from my .mp3 file. So the file exists as well. Also if I try to play it with an audio player it works well. But the exported video always is without audio...

Do you have an idea where the issue is?

By the way: I´m using it on a Flutter application.

Comment: try adding `-map 0:v:0  -map 1:a:0`

Comment: What this does?

Comment: chooses the output